# Add button over subview which is again over a superview

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, subview, addsubview

I have uiviewController as main view , then i have added subview called "supporteview". Now i am adding button programmatically on supportview.
the buttons are not visible due to some reason , but when i load buttons on main view i am able to see the buttons.

`[self.view addSubview:self.supportview];
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.supportView];
 [self.supportView addSubview:self.btn];
 [self.supportView bringSubviewToFront:self.button];`

I have added slider in supportView and then loading buttons.

Comment: Are you dynamically generating button or it is inside storyboard?

Comment: Dynamically generating.

Comment: Try to update the frame of your button. set the x an y origin to 0.of your button frame.

Comment: See i adding the frame in this way.
            float xCordPerTimeStamp = SLIDER_WIDTH/self.slider.maximumValue;
            float xcord = [playbyplay.GameTime floatValue] * 60;
            int finalx =(xCordPerTimeStamp *xcord) + startxoffset + XORIGIN;
            int finaly = 700;
            NSLog(@"final x is %d",finalx);
            if([playbyplay.Opponent isEqualToString:@"B"])
            {
                finaly = 740;
            }
            NSLog(@"final x is %d and y%d",finalx,finaly);
           
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(finalx, finaly, 3, 8);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add button 1st to the supportView then add supportView to your view. You can also use view inspector to see where the button is https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6

This will help you to check the frame and constraint at the runtime

Comment: Supportview is added in storyboard and on events i am generating button over supportview.

Comment: Then you don't need below lines  [self.view addSubview:self.supportview];
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.supportView]; Simply add button on supportView

Comment: but it is not displaying

Comment: Can you try view debugging? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html , It is very simple and help you to see the views and frame at run time

Comment: Or try to set background color to red or green of supportView(just to test), might be its constraint are not set properly.

Comment: I have checked that constraint are properly set.